# Neo4j: Cypher query - how to find paths with length greater than 4

Tags: neo4j

I have a database that has ~1000k nodes and ~168k relationships and I want to find all paths between two nodes a and b where node a is bounded with a given property.
I tried the following cypher queries:

```
start n=node(*) match (n)-[r*1..5]->(m) where n.URI=~'.*Jacob_T._Schwartz.*' return n.URI,r,m;

match p=(n)-[r*3..5]->(m) where n.URI=~'.*Jacob_T._Schwartz.*' return p;

match p=allShortestPaths((n)-[r*..10]->(m)) where n.URI=~'.*Jacob_T._Schwartz.*' return p;
```

However, all these queries didn't return paths of length > 4. I am pretty sure there exist paths with length of 5. Is there a way to get paths of length greater than 4?

Btw, I am using neo4j-shell to connect remotely to a server and I already set wrapper.java.initmemory and wrapper.java.maxmemory to 5000.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Just set 5 as the minimum if you only want paths with length > 4.

`[*5..]`

But I recommend also setting a maximum.

`[*5..15]`

Comment: Thank you so much, Nicole. Will try it!